# How can I most easily make TLS over TLS proxy commands from python?

Tags: python, ssl, https, proxy, python-requests

I'm looking to connect to some HTTPS/TLS sites, over a proxy, where connections to the proxy itself are also made over HTTPS/TLS, from a heavily requests dependant python application.

`urllib3` (and, therefore the `requests` library) does not currently support this.

I'd rather not go down the rabbit hole of monkey-patching urllib3/requests to allow this to happen (unless someone else has already done it?)

What are some alternatives that might easily work for me? I've considered setting up a squid proxy, but that doesn't seem to be trivial (is it trivial?)

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is, it's not possible.

The longer answer is, it's possible, but not trivial and not easy.

But, this is likely to soon change - follow [this pull request](https://github.com/urllib3/urllib3/pull/1679) for status and updates